# Mysql query to select from database where term occurs more than x amount of time

Tags: mysql, database, search

I have a table filled with urls. It has 2 columns id and url.

I'm looking for a query that would be able to return domain names that appear more than 1000 times in the database.

What would be an efficient way to do this? I realize it will be fairly resource intensive and it will not be run frequently.

The urls are full urls

Ex:

```
http://test.com/page1.html
http://test.com/page2.html
http://test.com/page3.html
```

So there urls will not be the exact same, it is not just the domain stored in the url field.

Comment: Hey, check out my answer for a long term and scalable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  URL_COLUMN,  '://', 3 ) ,  '/', 3 ) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE group by
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  URL_COLUMN,  '://', 3 ) ,  '/', 3 )
having  count(*)> 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(ColID) AS Total, Col1, Col2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DomainColumn
HAVING Total > 1000
```

EDIT:

you need to use `SUBTRING_INDEX` within GROUP BY to achieve what you want.

My Suggestion: **NORMALIZE** your tables. You should not be saving data like that, you can save Domain in a separate column.

Comment: The urls will all be different, sorry if it wasn't clear I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance I would recommend including 2 triggers to normalize the data for faster performance.  Add another column named `"domain"`

Make 2 triggers "Before Update" and "Before Insert"

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.url,'/',3);
END
```

Now after those triggers are set you can do a simple

```
UPDATE `table` SET domain = domain
```

Which will use the trigger.

Then you can use the following query very efficiently.

```
Select `id`,`url`,count(`domain`) as `Total` 
FROM `table` 
GROUP by `domain` 
HAVING `Total` > 1000
```

That should do it.
**Also Index the domain column.**

Comment: Note that `count` is a keyword in mysql so its not a good idea to use `count` as a column name unless you do \`Count\`

Comment: The urls will all be different, sorry if it wasn't clear I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3) domain 
     , COUNT(*) total  
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP  
    BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3)
```